# Knockout options binding with array of objects remove issue

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

In this view model I'm binding a drop down list with objects. when I want to clear the items from the drop downlist, I've provided selected item with "null" but it does clear the drop down but doesn't remove the selected Item. please see the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/aroor/Su8Zq/36/

```
<select data-bind="optionsCaption: ' ', options: stations, optionsText : 'name' ,value: selectedStation">   </select>
   <button data-bind="click: clearSelectedStation">Clear</button>
     <br>   
      <span data-bind='text : selectedStation().name'></span>



var ClearSelectionViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.station= ko.observable();
    self.selectedStation = ko.observable();



    self.stations = ko.observableArray([{name :'CLT'},{ name : 'PHL'},{ name :'PHX'},{ name :'PIT'}]);

    self.clearSelectedStation = function () {
    self.selectedStation(null);
   };
   };

 ko.applyBindings(new ClearSelectionViewModel());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binding of

```
<span data-bind='text : selectedStation().name'></span>
```

is throwing an error when selectedStation is null.  The binding tries to find the .name property of the value returned from selectedStation(), but "null" has no .name property.  There are a couple ways to address this:

Wrap your binding in a "with" binding which will protect you from nulls,

```
<!-- ko with : selectedStation -->
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

or create a computed on your view model to handle the null

```
var ClearSelectionViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    ...
    self.selectedStationName = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.selectedStation() ? self.selectedStation().name : '';
    }
    ....
}

<span data-bind="text: selectedStationName"></span>
```

or use an If/IfNot binding to handle the null-case.

You can [read a bit more about these on my blog](http://ryanrahlf.com/showing-an-empty-ui-with-knockout-js-dealing-with-default-data/).

I hope that helps!